# Tablas dinámicas - Pegar en Reporte como si fuera un Gráfico

Tags: excel, excel-2013, hoja-de-cálculo-tabla-dinámica, tabla-dinámica

Intento hacer un resumen ejecutivo en Excel, se compone de algunas tablas dinámicas y gráficos, nada complicado. Pero al poner una tabla debajo de otra, es probable que: -Haya mucha diferencia en el tamaño de columna que requieren, por ejemplo si en la misma columna, una tabla tiene texto y la otra una cantidad. -La tabla de arriba pase a tener muchas filas.
Principalmente me molesta la diferencia en las columnas, por el espacio desperdiciado, se que es algo natural de Excel y no pretendo cambiar eso.

Pero, esta es la parte importante, probando con Power BI, Tableau, Qlik y MicroStrategy (todas en su versión gratuita), veo que se pueden poner tablas tan independientemente como se colocan gráficos. ¿Se puede hacer algo parecido en Excel, colocar las tablas como si fueran gráficos?

No quiero pegar la tabla como imágen, ya que la idea es hacer el reporte actualizable. No quiero ocupar Macros, porque el reporte lo va a ocupar alguien con menos conocimiento en Excel. Tengo Excel 2013 Standard, por lo que Power Pivot está fuera de alcance. No sirve la opción de la tabla de datos del gráfico, ya que no permite moverla con libertad. Finalmente, todos los programas nombrados mas arriba fueron descartados por diversas razones, por eso estoy tratando de hacerlo en Excel.

Comment: Puede usar Power View en excel, funciona como Power BI y es fácil de activar.

Comment: Hola. ¿Podrías postear una imagen de lo que tienes, y otra imagen de lo que te gustaría conseguir? Por entender mejor la idea de lo que vides.

Comment: @virtualdvid Buena idea, pero como Power Pivot, requiere del Excel Pro y solo tengo el Standard.  
 Francamente me cuesta poner una imagen, la preparé, pero ahora no se cómo subirla; de todas maneras no creo que sirva.   
En fin, gracias de todas formas.

Comment: Estuve leyendo y parece que si se instala esta actualización se puede luego activar los complementos, Power Pivot y Power View.  [Link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2817425/description-of-the-excel-2013-update-august-13-2013)

Comment: @virtualdvid Me dice que no hay productos que serían afectados. O sea que no es para este Excel.  
Pensandolo de otra manera, quizás esa es la ventaja de tener el Excel Pro; por lo que no van a ofrecer algo tan especializado en una versión menor.

Answer (score 0):

lo que se acostumbra en algunas ocasiones es acomodar todas las tablas dinámicas en una hoja y en otra hoja destinada al dashboard utilizar una combinación de controles (controles activex) en especifico una barra desplazadora y la función `DESREF` (versión español) con esto controlarías el tamaño de las matrices y el acomodo de la información y para controlar la selección de criterios te apoyas con `segmentadores de datos`.

Comment: En realidad no controlas el tamaño, las columnas seguirán acomodandose o dependiendo de otros datos; por ejemplo si en la misma columna tienes un texto largo y en otras filas una cantidad pequeña, el tamaño de columna se adapta al texto, y terminas con espacio desperdiciado en la "cantidad". Por otro lado, a modo de compartir, en lugar del 'DESREF' encuentro mejor una fórmula de lista:
'{=SUMA(SI('Construcción'!$A$7:$A$13<>"Total general";SI('Panel'!$A$1='Construcción'!$B$6:$M$6;'Construcción'!$B$7:$M$13)))/-1000}'